# Creating array variable in collection loop

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I get data from query and running a foreach loop on it.

```
foreach($result as $data)
{
    $myVar[$data->flag][$data->year]['totalActions'] += $data->totalActions;
}
```

And getting this error `Undefined variable: myVar`

When I create a variable before loop like `$myVar = []`

Then it gives me the error `Undefined index: All`

Here `All` is value of `$data->flag`

How to handle this?

Comment: Where is `contractDetails` here?

Comment: sorry, it is $myVar. Edit my question now

Comment: what is the data type of `$data->year` (string ?)  and `$data->totalActions` (int ?) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all you need to define `$myVar` (before `foreach`) as you did: `$myVar = [];`

second you need to define/isset `$myVar[$data->flag]`, `$myVar[$data->flag][$data->year]` and `$myVar[$data->flag][$data->year]['totalActions']` inside the `foreach`

in summery the whole snippet of code will be like so:

```
$myVar = [];

foreach($result as $data)
{
    $myVar[$data->flag] = isset($myVar[$data->flag]) ? $myVar[$data->flag] : '';
    $myVar[$data->flag][$data->year] = isset($myVar[$data->flag][$data->year]) ? $myVar[$data->flag][$data->year] : '';
    $myVar[$data->flag][$data->year]['totalActions'] = isset($myVar[$data->flag][$data->year]['totalActions']) ? $myVar[$data->flag][$data->year]['totalActions'] : 0;
    $myVar[$data->flag][$data->year]['totalActions'] += $data->totalActions;
}
```

or simply ignore the the errors by using `@` before `$myVar` so you can do so:

```
$myVar = [];

foreach($result as $data)
{
    @$myVar[$data->flag][$data->year]['totalActions'] += $data->totalActions;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create and init the `$myVar` before the `foreach` and init with the zero value if key isn't exists.

```php
$myVar = [];

foreach($result as $data)
{
    if (!isset($myVar[$data->flag][$data->year])) {
        if (!isset($myVar[$data->flag])) {
            $myVar[$data->flag] = [];
        }

        $myVar[$data->flag][$data->year] = ['totalActions' => 0];
    }

    $myVar[$data->flag][$data->year]['totalActions'] += $data->totalActions;
}
```